# For my form navigation buttons' code, "GoToRecord , , acNext" is skipping through all my forms to the last record

Tags: vba, ms-access

Whenever I try to use my navigation button, it skips to the very end and starts a new form under "New" instead of going to the next record. Not at all sure why. My data entry is being enabled and disabled before and after switching the record, that way my save as pdf button stays specific to the form the operator is using.

I want to know if there's a way to focus on my associated table's autonumber category, maybe it's not referencing the right field when it looks for the next record? Not sure. Haven't seen this problem anywhere

```
Forms!frmFurnaceLoad.DataEntry = False

If Me.CurrentRecord < Me.Recordset.RecordCount Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
Else
    '[If the condition is not true, then we are on the last record, so don't go to the next one]
End If

Forms!frmFurnaceLoad.DataEntry = True
```

Comment: Makes no sense to me. A save as pdf button will always be specific to the current record or the record id you pass.

Comment: Really? If data entry is set to no, and my recordset navigation menu reads 1 of 11, my export will without fail save or print all of those 11 forms... I'm baffled too, dude

Comment: I'm realizing now that by declaring dataentry again, it automatically is going to load a new form. Maybe I can figure out a way to code around this.

Comment: What trigger event is this code behind? Prev/Next button clicks?

Comment: My new code updated works based on the fact that it changes data entry to false if no already, and will then cycle through records accordingly. Data entry is set to yes upon form load, making the operator face a new form everytime, but still gives them the ability to go back. When the last sheet reached, DataEntry is turned back to true, making a new sheet open. However, now I have to solve the problem that is all my sheets get exported, not just the one I'm currenty on. Is there a fix for this?